# Ring Isomorphism Between Field of Fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> If $R\DeclareMathOperator{\Frac}{Frac}$ is a domain with $F = \Frac(R)$, prove that $\Frac(R[x]) \simeq F(x)$.

The way I solved this problem was by defining $f : \Frac(R[x]) \to F(x)$ by $f([h(x),g(x)]) = \frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$, which is sensible since $g(x) \neq 0$. I then proceeded to show that it is well-defined, a ring homomorphism, and bijective.

But I am wondering whether there is a way to use the following theorems to cut down on some of the work:

> (1) If $R$ is a field, then $R \simeq \Frac(R)$. More precisely, show that the ring homomorphism $f : R \to \Frac(R)$, given by $r \mapsto [r,1]$, is an isomorphism
>
> (2) If $A$ and $R$ are domains and $\varphi : A \to R$ is a ring isomorphism, then $[a,b] \mapsto [\varphi(a), \varphi (b)]$ is an isomorphism.
>
> (3) Let $R$ be a domain and let $\varphi : R \to k$ be an injective ring homomorphism, where $k$ is a field. Prove that there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi : \Frac(R) \to k$ extending $\varphi\,$; i.e., $\phi |_{R} = \varphi$.

I found a solution online which seems to use them, although it was so poorly written that I had, for the most part, trouble following it. I have tried to think about how to use these theorems, but it seems that using them will, in the end, amount to the same thing I did already. Can you see anyway of using them?

Comment: there is a great answer to the question you recently deleted, re-post it so i can answer it, or give me your email to send you the answer.

Comment: @Ahmad I recently deleted a question? I don't recall doing this. What was the question about?

Comment: sorry, it must be another user with similar profile photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* (a). Show that there is an injective ring homomorphism $R[x] \longrightarrow F(x)$. Then use (3) to get a map from $Frac(R[x]) \longrightarrow F(x)$.

(b) Show that there is an injective ring homomorphism $F[x] \longrightarrow Frac(R[x])$. Again use (3) to get a map from $F(x) \longrightarrow Frac(R[x])$.

(c) Use the uniqueness property stated in (3) to show that the above maps are inverse to each other.

Comment: Okay. Let $f : R[x] \to F(x)$ be defined by $f(p(x)) = \frac{p(x)}{1} = p(x)$, which is clearly an injective ring homomorphism, and therefore there exists $\phi_1 : Frac(R[x]) \to F(x)$ extending $f$, which handles part (a). However, I am having trouble finding an injective homomorphism $g : F[x] \to Frac(R[x])$. I tried $\sum [a_i,b_i] x^i \mapsto [\sum a_i x^i,1]$ and $\sum [a_i,b_i] x^i \mapsto [\sum a_i x^i, \sum b_i x^i]$, but I don't think either of these are injective.

Comment: @user193319 There is a natural inclusion of $F[x]$ in $Frac(R[x])$, use that inclusion. $\sum[a_i, b_i]x^i \mapsto \sum[a_i, b_i]x^i$.

Comment: @Krish : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540653/describing-equivalence-classes-and-finding-the-quotient-for-a-relation I gave up on finding the instructions on how to invite you to a chatroom. Please note that in your edits to the question linked above, everything you did was good except one thing: you wrote $A/\sim$ instead of $A/{\sim}.$ Notice the difference: $$ \begin{align} & A/\sim \\ \\ &A/{\sim} \\ {} \end{align}$$ The point is that \sim is a binary relation symbol and therefore has a certain amount of space before and after it for things like $x\sim y.$ But when........

Comment: ....it is used only as a noun, then the spacing in $x\sim y$ is not appropriate. The solution is to make sure nothing precedes or follows it. And that is what is done when one writes $A/{\sim}$ instead of $A/\sim. \qquad$