# Describing equivalence classes and finding the quotient for a relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

The set $A = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}. (x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2)$ if $x^2_1+y^2_1 = x^2_2+y^2_2$.

I need some help describing the equivalence classes and describing all elements in $A/{\sim}$. Any help in describing how to figure out this would be really helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you had any thoughts on this question so far?

Comment: Ever seen the equation of a circle (centered at the origin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x_1^2+y_1^2 = x_2^2+y_2^2$ if and only if $\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2} = \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2},$ and $\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}$ is the distance from $(0,0)$ to $(x_1,y_1).$ Thus two points are equivalent precisely if they're at the same distance from the origin. From that you can see what the equivalence classes look like.

Comment: Yah, I sort of figured that much. Maybe what I'm not sure of is what exactly an equivalence class necessarily is. Would I then say that each equivalence class is the the points that are equidistant from the origin to each other? ie {(1,2), (2,1)}

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you very much for the information related to the edit. I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalence class of a point $(x_1,y_1)$ under the relation given here is the set of all points on the circle in the plane with the centre at the origin and radius equal to $\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2)}$. I hope you are satisfied with this answer